# I play a level 11 dwarf fighter in DnD 4e, is there any kind of loophole that would stop me from aging?

Tags: dnd-4e

Due to some reckless play my dwarf has lost about half his life span. Trying to get around this problem, is there any kind of loophole he could use to regain his full life span or gain immortality from aging? Other suggestions to handling the loss of my life span are appreciated.

From the way I interpreted my DM, my dwarf's life span was simply chopped off at the top: he isn't older, but his life energy was taken and he'll die sooner than normal. Looking up what did it, I see that he probably made it up himself, so there's also the possibility I can push my DM to let me pursue something that will allow me to get out of it.

So far I've found taking Bloodknight as my paragon path as a possible solution, but not one that I'm too excited about. Becoming a cyborg was suggested by someone in my party. The epics aren't really a solution since they the immortality also ends my career if I understood them correctly.

Comment: Why would Bloodknight prevent you from aging? I don't think there's anything in the official content that could help you here, except a few epic destinies, only one of which you'd even qualify for. Unless you'd like to petrified forever? :)

Comment: Re: epics and immortality, not really, EDs pretty much all have a way to *keep adventuring* but also a logical end point attached to them. However, the question is, what does having a shortened life span effect? the answer, mechanically, is...nothing.

Comment: Unless I keep losing my life span and it ends up killing me.


Bloodknight was suggested by my DM. I suppose the idea would be that I wouldn't really age but would require blood to sustain myself? The character builder kind of wonked out while I was looking at paragon paths and won't allow me to read up on the Bloodknight thing at the moment.

Comment: @Elgorath there is nothing mechanical in that PP that helps with aging.

Answer (score 13):

Let's start with step 1 here.:

The mechanics of 4e don't care how old you are. That's purely a role play decision, the length of your career is up to you, your DM and whatever narrative flavor you give your campaign. So this is not a hurdle if you don't want it to be. 
Second, if you start to think about how long a campaign *really* is, it's probably a few short years of game time to go from L1-L30.

So if you want to, you don't *have* to do anything.

If you do want to do something, there are some interesting options:

- When you would end your career, end your life and become a revenant. You might change classes, but Revenant, past life Dwarf is a solid option. Bonus roleplay points if you commit suicide to come back as undead.
- MC Druid and take the ED Master Hierophant, at L24 you will stop aging, get there before you are too decrepit to continue adventuring
- Depending on the source and affects of the aging you've undergone, the Remove Affliction ritual may take care of it.

There is only one source of premature aging I'm aware of from a WOTC official source. That is perilous archways from the Tomb of Horrors super adventure. This aging specifically can be cured with Remove Affliction *or* ages away after a set number of milestones (though repeated exposure can still kill you). However, if this is not the source of your character's aging (and you're a bit low level for this spot in the superadventure), ask your DM about what he expects the effects of this aging to be on the narrative and the mechanical effects(if any).

Since this seems more like a homebrew effect, the absolute best thing you can do is discuss remediation with your DM. She created the effect (or at least sourced it), so she will be the best possible person to discuss this with. We're not much help on the effects when there aren't well defined rules (4e is sort of light on this stuff, it's primarily driven by combat mechanics, with a secondary drive of skill mechanics, narrative mechanics are intentionally not well supported to allow for more narrative freedom).

Again, there aren't many sources on what to do about aging adventurers because 4e adventurers are assumed to be in their prime and fully capable, you'll have to work out the effects with your DM.